# Printing html ignores CSS stylesheets

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a very simple html page with a table element.

The document is styled with css. When I print the page it looks like there are no stylesheets at all. Wrong font, everything is wrong.

What's the problem here? Do I have to create a special css only for printing? In my case it would be the same.. Is that really necessary?

Comment: Show the HTML that you use to embed the CSS. Does it have a `media` attribute?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without the link to the page, I can only offer little advice.

- Make sure the link to the stylesheet
  in the header is correct. And it should look something like this:

  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/link/to/.css" media="all">`

I just noticed that you mentioned `print`. The `all` media type will work across web and print. However, if you wanted to explicitly state another stylesheet for `print` than replace the `all` with `print`.

- Check to see if the style are not
  being overridden by something else. As CSS *is* Cascading Style Sheets
- Get Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

If your stylesheet link has `media="screen"`, then it will be ignored by print. In that case you can create a separate print stylesheet with `media="print"` or just change your existing style sheet to `media="all"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `media` attribute is used to determine the stylesheet purpose. You need to make sure that it is set to `all` (for all purposes) or `print` (only used when printing).