# Strange printing problem

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, printing, phptal

We have a certain page in our site that when you print, it doesn't come out properly!

We also have a print button on the site that when you press it opens a "printing optimized" version of the page in a new popup window with background colors stripped, etc. It shows up correctly in that window but when I press the ok button on the print dialog it still looks terrible. I frankly don't even know where to begin with this problem. Any help would be great!

When you press print preview from the browser, it shows up terrible as well. How could a page look one way in your browser and look completely different when you press print preview? The page is made using phptal based templates (don't know if that's relevant)

Thanks!

Update:
I've tested with firebug and changing the media on my stylesheets. It seems like the main stylesheet for the page IS being applied to both screen and print (I have it set to all), it just looks differently it print preview than it does on my browser.

[This question was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957974/printing-html-ignores-css-stylesheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I realized that the images on that page were coming in as background images (in the div style="background-image...")! That is why the browser was dropping them and I was getting this strange behavior. If I change the images to actual foreground images (img tag) it works just fine!